# Getting a single digit integer for RHEL version using SED or AWK

Tags: bash, integer, converters, rhel

I can get the 5.8 or 6.4 number from looking at `/etc/redhat-release`, but I don't know how to get it converted from `5.8` to just `5`. The command I'm using so far is:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release | awk {'print $7'}
```

Which produces the `5.8`. How would I go about getting the single digit integer from that using bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or use `int()` function:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release | awk '{print int($7)}'


$ cat /etc/redhat-release | awk {'print $7'}
5.8
$ cat /etc/redhat-release | awk '{print int($7)}'
5
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a format specifier:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release | awk '{printf "%d", $7}'
```

Comment: At the end of your command, it seemed there was no newline, and thus my next prompt was right on top of the integer. Your command works just as I wanted. Thank you also.